# Multiplying numpy matrices in a faster way

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have 3 matrices which I would like to multiply `A * B * C`.

A is a very sparse matrix of dimensions `k x d`

B is a hadamard matrix of `d x d`

C is a diagonal matrix of `d x d`

d is of the order of 100,000 while k is of the order of 1000

can someone suggest if there is any way to represent sparse matrices in a better way and do this faster

Comment: Just to clarify, are you looking for something that improves on performance of `scipy.sparse` implementation? I think for your dimensions `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` should be reasonably fast.

Comment: I'm not aware of scipy.sparse, I'm looking into it. Thanks